# How to fix "googlemaps.exceptions.ApiError : REQUEST_DENIED"

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

It is my first time using google maps API to get data. I've already required one API key from google cloud platform. However, it still pops out this error "Googlemaps.exceptions.ApiError: REQUEST_DENIED (This API project is not authorized to use this API.)". Please help!

```py
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import io
import sys
sys.stdout=io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf8')
from googlemaps import Client
from pprint import pprint

API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY'

gmaps = Client(key=API_KEY)
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode("臺北市")
pprint(geocode_result)
```

```
googlemaps.exceptions.ApiError: REQUEST_DENIED (This API project is not authorized to use this API.)
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the Geocoding API web service you need to **enable** it on your project first. Follow the steps in [Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#enable-api-sdk). Also make sure your API key is [properly restricted](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key#restrict_key).

Hope this helps.